# How to change a column position in a spark dataframe with more than 22 columns?

Tags: scala, cassandra

I'm changing the column position of my DF, because I will put it into Cassandra.
The problems is that I have more that 22 columns and I get this error:

`<console>:1: error: too many elements for tuple: 38, allowed: 22`

I am using this procedure:

`scala> val columns: Array[String] = firstDF.columns`

```
columns: Array[String] = Array(HOCPNY, HOCOL, HONUMR, HOLINH, HODTTO, HOTOUR, HOCLIC, HOOE, HOTPAC, HODTAC, HOHRAC, HODESF, HOCDAN, HOCDRS, HOCDSL, HOOBS, HOTDSC, HONRAC, HOLINR, HOUSCA, HODTEA, HOHREA, HOUSEA, HODTCL, HOHRCL, HOUSCL, HODTRC, HOHRRC, HOUSRC, HODTRA, HOHRRA, HOUSRA, HODTCM, HOHRCM, HOUSCM, HODTUA, HOHRUA, HOUSER)
```

`scala> val reorderedColumnNames: Array[String] = (hoclic,hotpac, hocdan, hocdrs,hocdsl,hocol,hocpny,hodesf,hodtac,hodtcl,hodtcm,hodtea,hodtra,hodtrc,hodtto,hodtua,hohrac,hohrcl,hohrcm,hohrea,hohrra,hohrrc,hohrua,holinh,holinr,honrac,honumr,hoobs,hooe,hotdsc,hotour,housca,houscl,houscm,housea,houser,housra,housrc)`

```
<console>:1: error: too many elements for tuple: 38, allowed: 22
val reorderedColumnNames: Array[String] = (hoclic,hotpac,hocdan,hocdrs,hocdsl,hocol,hocpny,hodesf,hodtac,hodtcl,hodtcm,hodtea,hodtra,hodtrc,hodtto,hodtua,hohrac,hohrcl,hohrcm,hohrea,hohrra,hohrrc,hohrua,holinh,holinr,honrac,honumr,hoobs,hooe,hotdsc,hotour,housca,houscl,houscm,housea,houser,housra,housrc)
```

How can I solve?.

P.S. The table in Cassandra has this structure:

`CREATE TABLE tfm.foehis(hocpny text, hocol text,honumr int,holinh text,hodtto date,hotour text,hoclic int,hooe text,hotpac text,hodtac int,hohrac int,hodesf text,hocdan text,hocdrs text,hocdsl text, hoobs text,hotdsc int,honrac int,holinr int,housca text,hodtea int,hohrea int,housea text,hodtcl int,hohrcl int,houscl text,hodtrc int,hohrrc int,housrc text,hodtra int,hohrra int,housra text,hodtcm int,hohrcm int,houscm text,hodtua int,hohrua int,houser text, PRIMARY KEY((hoclic),hotpac,hocdan));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val reorderedColumnNames: Array[String] = (hoclic,hotpac,hocdan,hocdrs,hocdsl,hocol,hocpny,hodesf,hodtac,hodtcl,hodtcm,hodtea,hodtra,hodtrc,hodtto,hodtua,hohrac,hohrcl,hohrcm,hohrea,hohrra,hohrrc,hohrua,holinh,holinr,honrac,honumr,hoobs,hooe,hotdsc,hotour,housca,houscl,houscm,housea,houser,housra,housrc)
```

The issue is in the definition of the right hand side of this assignment. Let's take a quick look and what happens with a smaller example

```
scala> val x = ("hello", "world")
x: (String, String) = (hello,world)
```

`x` became a two element tuple! That's because in scala `(...)` is syntax for making a tuple not a sequence. Instead you should use something like

```
scala> val x = Seq("hello", "world")
x: Seq[String] = List(hello, world)
```

To make a sequence or

```
scala> val x = Array("hello", "world")
x: Array[String] = Array(hello, world)
```

to make an array. Depending on what you need.